# PHP7.0-FPM and Nginx don't work using unix sockets

Tags: nginx, socket, php7

I have a trouble that is not described in the web. I am using VPS Debian 8 **Nginx + PHP7.0-FPM**. My server gives php-files in a source code and does not compile them when I configure Nginx and PHP7.0-FPM to use **unix sockets** (I do it cause I've read it works faster then tcp connections).

**So what I really do and it does not work**:

1. edit /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params to comment fastcgi_pass parameter to use unix socket file:

> ```
> #fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
> ```

all my hosts include this file, so I need to configure own socket in each host file. I do it like this:

2. edit /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com I type fastcgi_pass parameter there

> ```
> location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
> fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
> fastcgi_pass      unix:/var/run/php/example.com.php7.0-fpm.conf;
>         include             /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
>
>         fastcgi_param       SCRIPT_FILENAME     /var/www/example.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
>         fastcgi_param       DOCUMENT_ROOT       /var/www/example.com/www;
>
>         fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/example.com/tmp/upload;
>         fastcgi_param       PHP_ADMIN_VALUE     session.save_path=/var/www/example.com/tmp/sessions;
>     }
> ```

3. edit main php7.0-fpm pool file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to listen socket (but now I cannot understand why i need it here):

   listen = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
4. edit my site's pool file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/example.com.conf to set up it own socket (so here it is necessary I think):

   listen = /var/run/php/example.com.php7.0-fpm.sock
5. restart services:

   service nginx restart && service php7.0-fpm restart

so this get my index.php downloading as it is when I visit any site page.

But if I use tcp socket `fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;` it works fine.

Comment: do not know why my question has no answers that help me. all my server configs are here http://tlito.ru/node/697/ please what is wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAfn3nOXmgM) for some reason tells to use `127.0.0.1:9000;` instead of `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` I wonder why?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have the wrong filename for `fastcgi_pass` it should be:

```
fastcgi_pass      unix:/var/run/php/example.com.php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Make sure that php-fpm is running and that the socket file exists and has the correct permissions for nginx to access the file.  If you have selinux installed and enforcing, you might also need to check its logs to see if it is blocking nginx from accessing the file.

On php-fpm's side, each of those configuration files in `pool.d` is a separate pool of PHP executables and each needs its own socket.  `www.conf` is not a "main" configuration file, it's a completely separate pool of processes and should be disabled/removed if you are not using it.  With both pools configured to use the same socket, there is certainly a conflict here.

Comment: I don't believe this is what's going on. If he had a problem with this, he would be getting 502 Bad Gateway errors.

Comment: I had 502 errors when I configured wrong filename, it was, yes, but now it is not.

Comment: I've made 777 permissions for socket file and it's owner and group is www-data - this user is in nginx.conf

Answer (score 2):

What's going on with the overly complicated `location`?

```
location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
```

I expect that your requests are not actually matching this.

All you really need is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

Comment: I tried. did not help

Comment: You'll need to post the complete `server` block, then.

Comment: here http://tlito.ru/node/697/

Answer (score 0):

Unix sockets have permissions

The socket connecting php and nginx is created by php7.2-fpm service in accordance with the config

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

this file has

```
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

once you start/restart this service

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service
```

it creates a file that represents a socket with the specified owner and group

```
ls -la /run/php
```

BUT Nginx is using another user by default, you can veify it in

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

> user  nginx;

Now it is up to you, how you want to adjust permissions. Either give more permissions to you socket file, or change a listening user, or change nginx user... you pick your answer.